# RewriteCond file exists

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Such a simple problem but htaccess and I have never got along.

1. Serve the file if it exists.
2. If the URI is just / and if index.html exists then serve index.html
3. Otherwise serve app.php

Here is .htaccess:

```cs
# Disable the directory processing, Apache 2.4
DirectoryIndex disabled xxx
    
RewriteEngine On
    
# Serve existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
    
# For / serve index.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond    index.html -f
RewriteRule .? index.html [L]
    
# Otherwise use front controller
RewriteRule .? app.php [L]
```

It works if I comment out the RewriteCond index.html -f line as long as index.html does in fact exists.  But I also want to check for index.php so I need the file exists check.  And if nothing else I'd like to understand why the posted lines do not work.

Comment: And what's up with the formatting?  Indented four spaces as always.

Comment: Drive by down voting.  Always so helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
# Disable the directory processing, Apache 2.4
DirectoryIndex disabled xxx
    
RewriteEngine On
    
# Serve existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    
# For / serve index.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.html [L]
    
# Otherwise use front controller
RewriteRule ^ app.php [L]
```

Remember that `RewriteCond` with `-f` or `-d` needs full path to the file or directory that's why you need to prefix the filename with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/`. No need to escape dots here.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to change the . back to .? in the last line to properly handle the case where there was no index.html file.  With just a . I would get access forbidden.  Was that a typo or is there some deep dark secret?

Comment: Actually last line should have been `RewriteRule ^ app.php [L]` to also match landing page, corrected now.