# How to verify (google) domain ownership with html file method in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, google-search-console

How to add an html file to prouve ownership of a domaine in a Symfony application ?

Here is my working solution but I think it's pretty ugly because :

1. I have to create a special route
2. I have to store the file outside of /web directory where I think it is supposed to live.

Step 1 - Create a route (src/mybundle/Ressources/config/routing.xml

```
my_route_name:
     path:      /google43d423494a0981c2.html
     defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Main:googleCheck}
```

Step 2 - Create a controler action

```
public function googleCheckAction(){
    return $this->render('google43d423494a0981c2.html.twig');
}
```

/!\ Carreful - trick 1 you need to rename the file with the .twig extention otherwise this won't work.

Now put the file under app/Resources/views/
You can also put the file in any of your bundle views, just change the path in the controler action.

What would be the best way to handle this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options:

1. Just put a HTML file in the `web/` folder and let the web server render it.
2. If necessary, you can store it outside of the Symfony project, and just tell your web server where to find it.
3. Alternatively, create a route in `routing.yml` and [serve it using the default controller] (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html) and store the template in the root of `app/Resources/views`.

   ```
   gwt:
       path: /google43d423494a0981c2.html
       defaults:
           _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
           template:    '::google43d423494a0981c2.html.twig'
   ```

I personally would choose option #2, because I wouldn't want to add a file which had nothing to do with the application into the repository.

Comment: Are you sure about 1 ? I'm pretty sure this lead to a 404 when you go to www.mydomain.com/google43d423494a0981c2.html

About 2 - so you mean edit apache/ngix conf file ?

3) Yes I tried this but it didn't work. I think this is because of the .twig extention trick. I tested it only with .html extention.

Comment: If you're using nginx, and using the default configuration as recommended by Symfony, then if the file exists it's going to return that file (because of the `try_files` statement). It's the same way it returns images, CSS and JavaScript files stored inside the web folder. That it happens to be an HTML file will be irrelevant for nginx.

Comment: OK if you're using Apache, it's slightly different - you need to use `mod_rewrite` with the `-f` condition (Apache's equivalent of nginx's `try_files`). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29321034/582278.

Comment: it actualy does work on localhost with the following url http://localhost/web/test.html but I think it will fail on prod because apache root is on /web so the url will be www.mydomain.com/google43d423494a0981c2.html and this will lead to a 404.  - I haven't checked your try_files option yet though.

Comment: It works on production or dev - I know because I've done it before. When you (or anyone) requests `googlexxx.html`, Apache will look for a file in the `root` location (whether that's `web/` is up to you to configure). If it's there, it will render it, otherwise it will pass the request to PHP to handle.

Comment: So you're right it's working on prod even without changing anything. This is definitly the best and easiest way to do ... I should have started by this. Funny I'm pretty sure I've try and this wasn't working this is why I came out with the route and twig tweak things. Anyway I validated your answer. Thank you.